# Prove by definition $f$ is differentiable in all point $\bar{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and find $df_\bar{v}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ a linear transformation. Prove by definition $f$ is differentiable in all point $\bar{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and find $df_\bar{v}$

My work:

We need see $lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{v}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{v})-df\bar{v}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=0$

Let $\bar{v},\bar{h}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then

$lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{v}+\bar{h})-f(\bar{v})-df\bar{v}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{v})+f(\bar{h})-f(\bar{v})-df\bar{v}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=lim_{\bar{h}\rightarrow\bar{0}}\frac{||f(\bar{h})-df\bar{v}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}$

In this last step i'm stuck. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $df_{v}=f$, try this.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition should be as follows. $f$ is linear. The derivative should be also linear. So there must be a connection between them!
Before doing any problem just ask yourself about what you know and what you wish to know. That's the clue! Good luck!